# issue in destructuring of object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-redux

I am not able to understand what is the issue in object restructuring.

[image]

```
getPendingSubscriptions = () => {
        let programId = this.props.programId
        const filter = {...this.filters, programId}
        apiDelegate.getPendingSubscriptions(filter).then(rst => {
            if (rst.status == 0) { // Success
                this.setState({
                    totalCount: rst.data.count,
                    data: rst.data.data
                })
            } else if(rst.status == -2) { // Authentication failed
                window.location = baseUrl.local+'/#/login'
            }
        })
    }
```

Below is my `package.json` code.

```
{
  "name": "@myapplication",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive",
    "start": "dotenv -e .env -- webpack-dev-server --hot --define process.env.dev --inline --port 80 --host localhost",
    "build": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.js --env.prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bowser": "^2.1.0",
    "classnames": "^2.1.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "create-react-class": "^15.7.0",
    "css-hot-loader": "^1.3.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "fbemitter": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "findup-sync": "^0.1.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.4.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.10",
    "i18next": "^21.6.3",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.2",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.3.5",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.0",
    "react-anything-sortable": "^1.7.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-bootstrap-date-picker-thecodingmachine": "^5.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-native-slider": "^2.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-slider": "^2.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^4.1.5",
    "react-color": "^2.13.8",
    "react-datepicker": "1.6.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.3",
    "react-i18next": "^11.15.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scrollable-anchor": "^0.6.1",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "react-signature-pad": "^0.0.6",
    "react-spinners": "^0.4.5",
    "react-star-rating": "^1.4.2",
    "react-stepzilla": "^4.6.3",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^5.1.0",
    "react-toastify": "^3.1.0",
    "react-toggle": "^4.0.2",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.1",
    "reactjs-localstorage": "0.0.5",
    "reactstrap": "^4.8.0",
    "reflux": "^6.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "superagent": "^3.8.1",
    "transform-class-properties": "^1.0.0-beta",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "xss": "^0.3.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "6.26.0",
    "canvas": "1.6.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "dotenv-cli": "2.0.1",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.3",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "jsdom": "11.2.0",
    "mocha": "^3.3.0",
    "mocha-jsdom": "^1.1.0",
    "node-libs-browser": "^2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "1.10.12",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.7",
    "react-tools": "0.13.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "source-map": "^0.6.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  }
}
```

Below is my entire code file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn} from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import 'react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css';
import {toast} from 'react-toastify';
import moment from 'moment'
import apiDelegate from '../Utils/Common/api'
import baseUrl from '../../base';

import TariffValuesDlg from '../Utils/ElectronicDocumentComponent/TariffValuesDlg';
import RecapFormDlg from '../Utils/ElectronicDocumentComponent/RecapFormDlg';
import ConfirmDlg from '../Utils/Common/ConfirmDlg';

export default class PendingSubscriptionsTab extends React.Component {
    filters = {
        page: 1,
        limit: 10
    }
    
    state = {
        isTariffValuesDlgOpen: false,
        isRecapFormDlgOpen: false,
        isConfirmDlgOpen: false,
        tariffValues: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getPendingSubscriptions()
    }

    getPendingSubscriptions = () => {
        let programId = this.props.programId
        const filter = {...this.filters, programId}
        apiDelegate.getPendingSubscriptions(filter).then(rst => {
            if (rst.status == 0) { // Success
                this.setState({
                    totalCount: rst.data.count,
                    data: rst.data.data
                })
            } else if(rst.status == -2) { // Authentication failed
                window.location = baseUrl.local+'/#/login'
            }
        })
    }

    nameFormatter = (cell, row) => {
        var rst = cell ? cell : ""
        rst = row.surname ? (rst ? `${rst}<br/>${row.surname}` : row.surname) : rst
        var rst = rst.replace(/'([^']+(?='))'/g, '$1');
        var rst = rst.replace(/"([^"]+(?="))"/g, '$1');
        return rst
    }
    dateFormatter = (cell) => {
        var date = "";
        if (cell && cell.hasOwnProperty('date')) {
          date = moment(cell.date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
        }
        return date;
    }
    tariffValuesFormatter = (cell, row) => {
        return (
        <a onClick={this.toggleTariffValuesDlg.bind(this, cell, row.id)}>
            Tarifer
        </a>);
    }
    fileListFormatter = (cell, row) => {
        if (cell && cell.length > 0) {
            return <div className="flex-col-container">
                {cell.map((file, index) => (
                <a href={`${baseUrl.api}/form/${row.id}/${file}`} target="_blank" key={index}>{file}</a>
            ))}</div>
        } else {
            return ''
        }
    }
    recapFormatter = (cell, row) => {
        var contractNum = null
        if (row.contractNum) {
            if (typeof row.contractNum === 'string') {
                contractNum = JSON.parse(row.contractNum);
            } else {
                contractNum = row.contractNum;
            }
        }
        var answers = row.recap
        if (typeof answers === 'string') {
            answers = JSON.parse(answers)
        }
        return (
            <a onClick={this.toggleRecapFormDlg.bind(this, answers, contractNum)}>
                Récap
            </a>
        )
    }
    statusFormatter = (cell, row) => {
        var rst = ""
        switch (cell) {
            case 1:
                rst = "En attente";
                break;
            case 4:
                rst = "Rejeté";
                break;
            case 2:
                rst = "Tarif envoyé ";
                break;
            case 3:
                rst = "En garantie";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return rst
    }
    actionFormatter = (cell, row) => {
        return (<div>
            <a onClick={this.openConfirmDlg.bind(this, row.id, 2)}>
                Valider
            </a>
            /
            <a onClick={this.openConfirmDlg.bind(this, row.id, 4)}>
                Refuser
            </a>
        </div>)
    }

    toggleTariffValuesDlg = (result, subscriptorId = null) => {
        const tariffValues = result;
        if (subscriptorId == null && this.state.subscriptorId && tariffValues) {
            apiDelegate.updateSubscriptionTariff(this.state.subscriptorId, tariffValues).then(rst => {
                if (rst.status == 0) { // Success
                    toast.info(rst.message, {position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT, preventDuplicate: "info-pending-subscription-tab"})
                } else if(rst.status == -2) { // Authentication failed
                    window.location = baseUrl.local+'/#/login'
                } else {
                    toast.error(rst.message, {position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT, preventDuplicate: "warn-pending-subscription-tab"})
                }
            })
        }
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            isTariffValuesDlgOpen: !prevState.isTariffValuesDlgOpen,
            tariffValues,
            subscriptorId
        }))
    }

    toggleRecapFormDlg = (answers, contractNum) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            isRecapFormDlgOpen: !prevState.isRecapFormDlgOpen,
            answers,
            contractNum
        }))
    }
    openConfirmDlg = (subscriptorId, subscriptionStatus) => {
        this.setState({
            isConfirmDlgOpen: true,
            subscriptorId,
            subscriptionStatus
        })
    }
    onConfirmDlgClose = isOK => {
        this.setState({
            isConfirmDlgOpen: false
        })
        if (isOK) {
            const {subscriptorId, subscriptionStatus, data} = this.state
            apiDelegate.updateSubscriptionStatus(subscriptorId, subscriptionStatus).then(rst => {
                if (rst.status == 0) { // Success
                    toast.info(rst.message, {position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT, preventDuplicate: "info-pending-subscription-tab"})
                    this.getPendingSubscriptions()
                } else if(rst.status == -2) { // Authentication failed
                    window.location = baseUrl.local+'/#/login'
                } else {
                    toast.error(rst.message, {position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT, preventDuplicate: "warn-pending-subscription-tab"})
                }
            })
        }
    }

    onSizePerPageList = (sizePerPage) => {
        const oldLimit = this.filters.limit
        this.filters.limit = sizePerPage
        if (oldLimit != sizePerPage) {
            this.getPendingSubscriptions()
        }
    }

    onPageChange = (page) => {
        const oldPage = this.filters.page
        this.filters.page = page
        if (oldPage != page) {
            this.getPendingSubscriptions()
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {
            data,
            totalCount,
            isTariffValuesDlgOpen,
            isRecapFormDlgOpen,
            isConfirmDlgOpen,
            tariffValues,
            answers,
            contractNum,
            subscriptionStatus
        } = this.state
        const {formData, fillType} = this.props
        const form = formData ? JSON.parse(formData) : null
        const confirmText = subscriptionStatus == 2 ? "Etes vous sur de vouloir accepter ?" : "Etes vous sur de vouloir refuser ?"

        return (
        <div>
            <BootstrapTable
                data={ data }
                remote
                fetchInfo={ {dataTotalSize: totalCount} }
                keyField='id'
                pagination
                options={{
                    onPageChange: this.onPageChange,
                    onSizePerPageList: this.onSizePerPageList
                }}
            >
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name' dataFormat={this.nameFormatter}>Noms</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='date_updated' dataFormat={this.dateFormatter}>Date demande</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='valid_offer_count'>Offre</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='tariff' dataFormat={this.tariffValuesFormatter}>Valeurs tarifaires</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='files' dataFormat={this.fileListFormatter}>Liste PJ</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='recap' dataFormat={this.recapFormatter}>Lien Récap</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='status' dataFormat={this.statusFormatter}>Statut</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='action' dataFormat={this.actionFormatter}>Action</TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
            <TariffValuesDlg
                isOpen={isTariffValuesDlgOpen}
                onToggle={this.toggleTariffValuesDlg}
                parent={this}
                tariffValues={tariffValues}
                fillType={fillType}
            />
            <RecapFormDlg
                isOpen={isRecapFormDlgOpen}
                onToggle={this.toggleRecapFormDlg}
                parent={this}
                formData={form}
                answers={answers}
                contractNum={contractNum}
            />
            <ConfirmDlg
                isOpen={isConfirmDlgOpen}
                closeModal={this.onConfirmDlgClose}
                title=""
                message={confirmText}
            />
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is legacy application so this is old code.

Comment: (1) Maybe unneeded but have you done `npm install`, or it might help to run `npm update`. (2) There might be unprintable characters present by accident, try retyping the line from scratch (without copy-paste).

Comment: can there be issue because of dependency? i dint do any change in this file, only did, yarn upgrade react-router-dom